# Get a item selected in listview when i generate context Menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I want get a selected item from a listview.

When maintain a longclick a listview item I get the context menu (everything works) but I want to know how to detect what is POSITION which to made ​​the longclick

1º declare the items for a context menu in

/res/menu/NAMEOFXMLUWANT.XML

like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/Abrir"
      android:title="@string/Abrir" />
<item android:id="@+id/Editar"
      android:title="@string/Edit" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Borrar"
      android:title="@string/delete" />
<item android:id="@+id/Alarma"
      android:title="@string/Alarma" />
</menu>
```

2º-AFTER in the class of u want do the context menu in LIST VIEW

lista = me listview

```
 lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Lista);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ficheros);
        lista.setLongClickable(true);

        lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

        lista.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { //here u set u rute
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

            }
        });
```

3º AND FINALY, u set u onclick to items

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item 
            .getMenuInfo(); 
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.Editar:
    System.out.println("Editar");
    return true;
  case R.id.Borrar:
        System.out.println("borrar");
    return true;
  case R.id.Abrir:
        System.out.println("Abrir");
    return true;

  case R.id.Alarma:
        System.out.println("Alarma");
    return true;

  default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

for me all this WORKS :), but i want get select item with the long click, thx for reading ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

menuInfo.position solved my problem, courtesy @Luksprog