# I have a listview, on click appears a context menu. Any way to know the context menu over which listview item appeared?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-contextmenu

Have a listview, on click appears a context menu. Any way to know the context menu over which listview item appeared?

Comment: wait, so do you want to tell the context menu which list item was clicked?

Comment: yes. after the contextmenu appeared from where i know which listview item was cliked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int listViewPosition;
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        listViewPosition = position;
    }
 });
```

Then you can use `listViewPosition` in

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    Log.d("ListView clicked Item", ""+listViewPosition);
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: @user3190360 Welcome to Stackoverflow, some FYI for you, always upvote answers that helped you else others will feel discouraged to help you. Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

You get the selected item from the listview:

```
lv.getSelectedItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    }
 });
```

Where `position` is the position of the item that was clicked in the `ListView`.

Comment: Yes I know, but public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) is another method, in which I need this.

Comment: When the item is clicked, you can save the position or Object in a field (declare it at the beginning of your activity) and then in OnCreateContextMenu you can easily just access that field.

Comment: Yes, but the context menu appears on long click and the clickListener do nothing on long click so i can't save the id.

Comment: then use `setOnItemLongClickListener` instead.

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249943/get-a-item-selected-in-listview-when-i-generate-context-menu